# Entity Framework code-first doesn't create database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use code-first in Entity Framework to generate the database, but it's not working. Here's my connection string in the `app.config` of the console application:

```
<add name="BlogDbContext" 
     connectionString="data source=myserver; initial catalog=CodeFirstDemo; integrated security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and here's my `program.cs` file code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstDemo
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In package manager console I tried: `enable-migration`, then `add-migration`, then `update-database`.. but nothing happened.

I tried connection string as suggested in other questions like this:

```
<add name="CodeFirstDemo.BlogDbContext" 
     connectionString="data source=myserver; initial catalog=CodeFirstDemo; integrated security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say "nothing happened", do you mean you didn't get any response at all from the commands in the console?  they should have either given you success or failure messages, at least.....

Comment: @Claies this is what I get: Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.

Comment: and when you use the `-Verbose` flag, does it show the SQL statements?

Comment: it says: Target database is: 'CodeFirstDemo.BlogDbContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention). what does that mean? @Claies

Comment: it means it is using SQL LocalDB, and has probably put a database file in the \App_Data\ directory of your project.

Comment: But isn't my configuration for the app.config right? what should I do to make it create it according to the connection string @Claies

Comment: It uses whatever connection string you supply, or a convention if you don't.  You can have more than one connection string in your app.config, and ef doesn't assume which one you want, if you don't tell it which, you get the generic one.  See the provided answer, links for more information

Comment: @Claies but the answer links suggests I use the constructor. According to what I read about EF, I don't have to use the constructor for this. can you tell me the solution?

Comment: You read something partially correct.  You don't need a constructor to use the automatic connection string.  You do need a constructor if you want to provide your own connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty constructor with the following signature to reference the connection string you already added to your app.config:

```
  public BlogDbContext()
        : base("Name=BlogDbContext")
  {
  }
```

You don't need to use migration to create your database.You can do what I show below in your `Main` method:

```
using (var context = new BlogDbContext())
{
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

Comment: The examples online didn't specify a call to the base class. They just use it as I do, and it creates the database. I don't think you really need to do this. The database gets created once you call: update-database from the package manager console

Comment: but your database hasn't been created yet, when you executed add-migration there is nothing to compare. that's why you need to create your database first. After that, if you change your model, then call add-migration and update-database commands to update your database with the new changes

Comment: Check this page:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx. It proves what I explain above in my comment.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using code-first you should have these codes that look alike to the following example :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Post");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

These will create the database table of your entities.

Comment: That has no effect on the database creation. It is not necessary to override OnModelCreating for EF to do its work. It is only needed to change the default behavior when something different is required.

Comment: Right I understand, could the issue be that the OP's connectionstring is not valid?